# Let's change our favicon to 

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I propose we request for our favicon to be changed to , a globe.

Credit for this proposal goes to [WBT](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285457/172266) but it's on this meta site we need to decide whether to adopt this.  Please share your thoughts.

(Alternatives would be  or ; I propose  because it's closest to the prime meridian, but ultimately it's arbitrary)

Comment: I agree that the site's favicon should be changed & I've already voted for my preference from the answers so far. My understanding however is that it is unlikely to happen while the site is still in beta. Only sites that have graduated from beta get their own favicon & presentation "theme": fonts, colours, etc. But if we can get it done sooner even better.

Comment: Any update on this? How to progress?

Comment: @Tbb Thanks for reminding me.  I will ask the community team on Monday (I expect they don't work on the weekend).

Comment: Any updates? By the way, I can't see any of the icons on the question. They show as squares only.

Comment: @CamiloRada It appears that it's not a priority for the community team.

Comment: @CamiloRada it depends on your device. Not all devices and operating systems fully implemented the emoji unicode range, but these are becoming exceedingly rare nowadays. The comment was made in March 2018, and there is a good chance that by now (July 2019) you will be able to see the icons if you are using a properly updated device.

Comment: @CamiloRada Until today this question has not had the [tag:feature-request] tag, now it has; perhaps that helps.

Answer (score 6):

Agree. I guess Africa-centered would good, as we use it as the reference for plate reconstruction.

Answer (score 5):

Or we can make it Australia centered because that's where the oldest Earth materials are found? Doesn't matter. I'll vote for whatever makes the transition quicker and easier!

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative would be .

Answer (score -1):

TBH, I think the one with North and South america would suit this site best *(at least in my opinion)*. :)